# Build IOS application on Windows Bootcamp

Tags: ios, windows, macos, xamarin

I have a macbook pro and installed windows using bootcamp. Now I am developing IOS applications using Xamarin in Visual Studio on Windows. I know that a mac is needed to build an IOS application from windows. But the scenario is my laptop having OSX and Windows partitioned. Then how can I build IOS applications? Please advise.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio/Xamarin to develop an iOS app, you need a **running** Mac to connect to in order to compile/debug it. 1) Either run Windows as a virtual machine (NOT Bootcamp) on your Mac via VMware or Parallels or 2) Install Xamarin Studio on OS-X and use it instead of Windows/Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there any free parallels available?